# Multiple If condition and validate TRUE FALSE

Tags: c++11, if-statement

```
#include <iostream>    
using namespace std;

int main(){
int x,y,z;    
int a,b,c;
cout<<"Enter Values of first set: ";
cin>>x;    
cin>>y;    
cin>>z;    
cout<<"Enter Values of first set: ";
cin>>a;    
cin>>b;    
cin>>c;    
if(x!=a || y!=b || z!=c)
{
//some statements
}    
else
{
}    

}
```

when i run this code is transfer control to else but i don't know which one or two conditions getting false or may be all getting false

i want to know in return that which if condition was TRUE and which was FALSE but only with single if ,I don't wanna make multiple if and else.Thanks

Comment: Why did you include the [tag:java] tag?

Comment: what is this got to do with **java** or **C#**. Anyways, just print the `boolean`s out on the screen, to see which is `false`

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/if_else_statement_in_java.htm

Try looking up what an if statement does. You don't set any variable so how could they possibly equal one another?

Comment: sorry its my first question on Stack-overflow ,but i think its same in java except include

Comment: @Shashwat kindly can you show me how can i do this

Comment: By which condiition you mean which of the `x!=a`, `y!=b` and `z!=c`? Be aware you haven't assigned any values to any of your variable, so never run this code - it's undefined behaviour to try to read a variable you haven't set

Comment: You better read [ask]. Only include tags that are relevant to the question. Format your code. Use only real code that works (in this code, there are no values in `x`, `y`...). Do research, make it easier to answer you.

Comment: @RealSkeptic now i think i improved my question

Comment: @doctorlove now i changed code

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is some pretty nasty if construct to set a state with each condition like this:

```
int s = 0; // state
if(x!=a && s=1 || y!=b && s=2 || z!=c && s=3)
```

so `int s` would be the state of the first condition that is true.. but I would not do that :) just use multiple if's if possible

if you want to know if multiple of those conditions are true, you can also do that with bit logic inside the if, if you really need that I can extent this answer.

Comment: posted my comment as an answer, since it might actually be useful

Comment: yeah everyone on internet is suggesting nested if but is there no solution to check which multiple if condition is false ?

Comment: so does that answer your question or you want to check if multiple of those conditions might be true? that will even get nastier :D

Comment: If you want different behaviour depending on which subcondition holds, a subclause is exactly the situation this is designed for. If you want to check against multiple conidtions, then just use lots of ifs, instead of the short-circuiting `||`